# How to send (SQL)Connection to another Activity | Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to send a Connection object to another activity because I don't want to reconnect to the database again, but I don't know how to send it through the Intent. I read about Serializable and Parcelable but from what I see I can't use them. Another solution is using a Global class but this is bad solution. Please help.

Comment: What is your database ? SQLite ?

Comment: Is MS MySQL and I'm using JTDS to connect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sent it throw Intent, another way could be to create a Singleton in your app to manage (open, close, get) the connection to database.

As this, all components (activities, ...) could share same connection.